# WAMP change PHP version 5.6.25 to 7.0.10

Tags: php, wamp

After changing the Php version in WAMP settings after typing "php -v" in cmd I see

"PHP 5.6.25 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2016 11:39:15)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies "

while in phpinfo () it is 7.0.10. Why is this error, how to fix it?

Comment: So you can just remove 5.6 )

Comment: Your system path points at different PHP versions in server configuration (phpinfo) and command line (php -v).

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php

Comment: I changed the environment variable in Windows and it's ok, thx :)